# Why "Ich habe das Buch, das du haben wolltest" and not "Ich habe das Buch, das du wolltest haben"

Tags: word-order

In English, the sentence I'm trying to say is "I have the book that you wanted to have."

I don't understand why in the German translation, "haben" is not at the end of the sentence. I was under the impression that in German the infinitive verb always goes toward the end of the sentence.

Comment: What gave you that impression? German subclauses *almost always* end with the *finite* verb. It's only some complicated relative clauses that involve both auxiliary and modal verbs which break that rule. (Don't be confused by the fact that the infinitive ending *-en* is also the ending of some *finite* forms.)

Comment: I am not a native German speaker, but the second sounds awkwardly even for me. Recently, particularly younger Germans, started to not move the verb to the end, but I think in such sentences even they doesn't do it so. [Relevant text](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-weil-das-ist-ein-nebensatz-a-350013.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a statement, you would have been right about the infinitive going to the end:

> Du wolltest das Buch haben.

But since we have a subordinate clause, the verb is last, not second, so the finite verb goes last, with the infinite verb right before it.

> Ich habe das Buch, das du **haben wolltest**.

Answer (score 4):

That is because the finite verb is the modal verb **wollen** here, not *haben*. Such modal verbs take an infinitive describing the action further:

> Ich habe das Buch, dass du **haben** wolltest.

English does this, too, but the infinitive *to have* goes to the end, while in German, the finite form **wolltest** goes to the end.

Comment: Note that we have a subordinate clause here which is why the finite verb goes last. In a statement there would be a sentence bracket, with the infinite verb last. (Yes, German is complicated!)